# Get all data from a sap.m.table

Tags: sapui5

I have a sap.m.Table bound to an OData model and I want in my controller to get all the values in the table (using the ID or using the model).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to use the data for. The most general way of doing this is with the following snippet:

```js
var aData = (oTable.getItems() || []).map(function(oItem){
   // assuming that you are using the default model  
   return oItem.getBindingContext().getObject();
});
```

If you want to do something like a table export, check out this example:
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableExport/preview

**Later edit**: the [getBindingContext](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#getBindingContext) method expects a model name. If none is provided, then it uses the default model. If your OData model has a name, then you will have to pass this name to the getBindingContext method call.

Comment: Just to add to the answer: Use the model alias within the getBindingContext() call in case you have named models in your manifest.json file. [Link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#getBindingContext)

Comment: You are right. Included the info into the answer itself.